# How to merge the below arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays and I want to join them

```
function test()
        {

            var arr1 = [
                                {"id":1,"name":"Michale Sharma","gender":"Male","age":25,"salary":10000},
                                {"id":2,"name":"Sunil Das","gender":"Male","age":24,"salary":5000},{"id":3,"name":"Robin Pandey","gender":"Male","age":35,"salary":45000},{"id":4,"name":"Mona Singh","gender":"Female","age":27,"salary":12000}

                        ];
            var arr2 = [
                            {"Deptid":4,"Deptname":"IT"},
                            {"Deptid":1,"Deptname":"HR"},
                            {"Deptid":3,"Deptname":"HW"},
                             {"Deptid":24,"Deptname":"HW4"}
                        ];

            var res = Pack(arr1,arr2);
            console.log(res);
        }

    function Pack() 
    { 

        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);        

        args.join(',');       

        return args;
    }
```

I am expecting the output as

```
[{"Employees":[{"id":1,"name":"Michale Sharma","gender":"Male","age":25,"salary":10000},{"id":2,"name":"Sunil Das","gender":"Male","age":24,"salary":5000},{"id":3,"name":"Robin Pandey","gender":"Male","age":35,"salary":45000},{"id":4,"name":"Mona Singh","gender":"Female","age":27,"salary":12000}],"Departments":[{"Deptid":1,"Deptname":"IT"},{"Deptid":2,"Deptname":"HR"},{"Deptid":3,"Deptname":"HW"},{"Deptid":4,"Deptname":"SW"}]}]
```

But not able to. How to do it?

I have already tried with Concat() function of Javascript but it didn't helped.

N.B.~ As it can be assumed that there can be variable number of arrays in the Pack function.

Comment: `arr1.concat(arr2)`. This shows some lack of Google. I've looked for this 10 minutes ago and found it in 1 minute.

Comment: 1. join(',') will create a string - you don't want to. 2. You'll have to pass such arguments as "Departments", "Employees" somehow. Finally you don't want to join these arrays at all. You want to return { Employees : args[0], Departments: args[1] }

Comment: Now that I look closely to the output, your title is **way** off. You want to do `[{'Employees':arr1,'Departments':arr2}]`. There's no need for functions and the likes.

Comment: They are asking more than just putting two arrays together.  It seems like they want to put two arrays to seperate objects in an array.  The "Employees" and the "Departments" object aren't specified anywhere in the code, but are expected in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you do something like:

```
var newArray = [ { "Employees": arr1, "Departments": arr2 } ]
```

Comment: That's what I said in a comment... Also, notice that you will want to enclose the names around `'`

Comment: This is by far the easiest method. @ismaelmiguel The `'` are not really needed.

Comment: @Fietsband You mean, *the only* method?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Double (not single BTW) quotes for key names are required for JSON. Not for Javascript as per the language grammar.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Well no, if I become really creative I can probably think of other methods to get the same result.

Comment: @Thrustmaster I know. But tons of times there's people coming with things like `var a='key', b={a:5};` and then they ask why `b.key` is undefined. This just disambiguates a little. In my opinion.

Comment: @Fietsband That would be a ton of long and slow code for something so simple. That's due to the lack of information.

Comment: why wouldn't OP just create it like this in the beginning though, instead of using arr1 and arr2 variables, just do it all inline?  It seems like OP was looking for a more generic solution... but that is just a guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arr1 = [
                                {"id":1,"name":"Michale Sharma","gender":"Male","age":25,"salary":10000},
                                {"id":2,"name":"Sunil Das","gender":"Male","age":24,"salary":5000},{"id":3,"name":"Robin Pandey","gender":"Male","age":35,"salary":45000},{"id":4,"name":"Mona Singh","gender":"Female","age":27,"salary":12000}

                        ];
            var arr2 = [
                            {"Deptid":4,"Deptname":"IT"},
                            {"Deptid":1,"Deptname":"HR"},
                            {"Deptid":3,"Deptname":"HW"},
                             {"Deptid":24,"Deptname":"HW4"}
                        ];

var json = {};
var jsonArr = [];

json.Employees = arr1;
json.Department = arr2;

jsonArr.push(json);

document.write(JSON.stringify(jsonArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

From the expected JSON, what you need is neither "merging", nor "concatenation". You want to put an array inside an object.

What you want is below:

```
var output = [{
    "Employees": arr1,
    "Department": arr2
}];
```

Note that `output` is an array according to your expectation. Why you need an array is something I dont understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test() {

        var arr1 = {"Employees" : [
                            {"id":1,"name":"Michale Sharma","gender":"Male","age":25,"salary":10000},
                            {"id":2,"name":"Sunil Das","gender":"Male","age":24,"salary":5000},{"id":3,"name":"Robin Pandey","gender":"Male","age":35,"salary":45000},{"id":4,"name":"Mona Singh","gender":"Female","age":27,"salary":12000}

                    ]};
        var arr2 = {"Departments":[
                        {"Deptid":4,"Deptname":"IT"},
                        {"Deptid":1,"Deptname":"HR"},
                        {"Deptid":3,"Deptname":"HW"},
                         {"Deptid":24,"Deptname":"HW4"}
                    ]};

        var res = Pack(arr1,arr2);
        console.log(res);
    }

function Pack() 
{ 
    var results = [];
    arguments.forEach(function(element){
        results.push(element);
    });
    return results;
}
```

Comment: You could just push the arguments into an array, no need for the for statement

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i put a little fiddle together for you, [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/7844rhv7/8/)

Most of your code stays the same, except I added this to your test function:

```
 var myObjToMerge = [{Employees:[]},{Departments:[]}];
 var res = Pack(myObjToMerge,arr1,arr2);
```

You need to give 'Pack' some object to merge the arrays to, so I created an arbritary array of objects modeled after your example.  Note that this array of objects can come from anywhere and this method doesn't require it to be known ahead of time like some of the other examples.

Then I changed the 'Pack' function:

```
function Pack() 
    { 
        var objToMerge = arguments[0];
        for(var i = 0;i<objToMerge.length;i++)
        {
            if(arguments.length > i+1)
            {
                var firstProperty = Object.keys(objToMerge[i])[0];
                objToMerge[i][firstProperty]= arguments[i+1];
            }
        }   


        return objToMerge;
    }
```

The idea here is that 'Pack' grabs the first argument, your object to merge the remaining arguments into.  I would suggest using function parameters, but that is your call.

Then, I iterate through the objects in the objToMerge array (there are two objects: Employees and Departments).
I assume that the remaining items in arguments is in the correct order and I grab the next item in arguments and assign to to the first property in the object I am currently looped in.

The line:

```
var firstProperty = Object.keys(objToMerge[i])[0];
```

Will return the string value of the first property in an object.  We then use this to set the next array in arguments to that property:

```
objToMerge[i][firstProperty]= arguments[i+1];
```

there are a great deal of assumptions here and ways to improve, but you can see that it works in the fiddle and you can improve upon it as needed.